# Web App Client using ImplicitAccessTokenProvider from Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, rfc6749

I am writing an OAuth 2.0 client application and I am trying to use `ImplicitAccessTokenProvider`. But the problem is that this class allows for access token request by sending POST request to `/oauth/token` Authorization Server's endpoint.

For my Authorization Server to support this different Implicit flow implementation, I should change the Authorization Server to support Implicit Grant type to accept access token requests through `/oauth/token`. But it violates RFC 6749 because an access token must be implicitly retrieved in response of Resource Owner's authorization.

Does anybody have written any Client application which relies on `ImplicitAccessTokenProvider` to share the experience?